# Ionic platform add android adds default cordova files

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Im doing an ionic project. I have made all the designs and components in the www folder.

But yesterday onwards whenever i tried to run the command `ionic platform add android` or  `cordova platform add android`  it adds the default cordova files. [image]

Its not adding the files in the www folder that i have made.
And also the `ionic build android` or `cordova build android` not doing anything.

Please help.

This problems came yesterday.
I didnt updated anything

Comment: `add` id for adding a platform to a project, you probably want `build`

Comment: I'm adding platform before building.
I have done many android projects using ionic. But this was the first time